# Mapping RGB Values to color names MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, colors, image-segmentation, matlab-cvst

I've been working on performing K-means clustering on images in different color spaces. The cluster centers are representative of the color value and I would like to describe the color value by a color name.

Example of the results of the clustering operation : 
[image: Orignal, Segmented Image]

I would now like to describe the color names of these 3 pixels (RGB values) from the segmented img:

```
 134.2263  146.4977  194.6406
 137.5899   78.5631   50.4859
 111.6383  131.4764   36.3863
```

to get outputs like : dark green, brown, light purple etc.

I'm thinking this is similar to using HTML color codes but I am not sure how to apply this in matlab.

There are similar questions on stackoverflow but related to python,java etc not matlab. Is there any matlab functionality which would make this feasible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution sketch:

Download a web page containing information about rgb values and matching names:

```
ctable = urlread('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_colors_%28compact%29');
```

Parse rgb values, each value happens to appear twice:

```
rgb_vals = regexp(ctable,'rgb\([0-9]+,[0-9]+,[0-9]+\)','match')';
rgb_vals = rgb_vals(1:2:end);
```

Parse color names: this might be a little bit more tricky, but possible. Just make sure the order matches the parsed list of rgb values, by examining a few pairs.

Finally, construct a KNN classifier, that is given a new rgb value find the closest rgb value in your table, and output the matching name. You can use Matlab's `knn`.

Another similar option is to look for an online rgb-to-name converter, and send a request to it each time you need.

**EDIT**
It might be easier to first split the content in `ctable` by line-endings, then when you find a line with rgb value you can look for the name in the following line.

Comment: +1 and thank you! but it may be a little too  complex for my application. Can you think of another way which it can be done simply using about 10 main colors e.g. red blue green yellow etc. but with descriptions such as dark, light? 

I can only think of estimating the ranges of these colors in hsv and then mapping it to a defined label. Would a KNN classifier be applicable in this case as well? 
Thanks.

Comment: It should work the same for a shorter table (which you can also find online, or construct yourself). the drak/light can be based in some threshold. If it doesn't work for hsv you can always convert hsv->rgb and do the knn in rgb space

Comment: Are there set ranges for dark/light colors? or do I just estimate from a "color picker" app?

Comment: I don't know of any range, but it doesn't mean there isn't any. You can try a threshold on the `v` value of the `hsv` and see what works best